# row_spec() function from kableExtra does not create a horizontal line in html output

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I would like to add a horizontal line under one of the rows in my kableextra table. The parameter hline_after for row_spec function is supposed to add the horizontal line under the row:

[row_spec documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kableExtra/versions/0.9.0/topics/row_spec)

However, this does not happen, the parameter appears to have no effect at all.

Example code:

```
x <- knitr::kable(head(mtcars), "html")
kableExtra::row_spec(x, 2, hline_after = TRUE)
```

[image: Output]

Does anyone know why this happens and is there another way to add the horizontal line to the table (using the same packages).

Thank you

**EDIT**
As Lyngbakr pointed out, the function works when output is set to LaTeX.

Comment: It works for me in LaTeX. It doesn't, however, for html. Looking at the code, this isn't surprising since `hline_after` isn't even passed to `row_spec_html`, the internal function that actually creates the table in html. It is passed to `row_spec_latex`, though.

Comment: You are right, I had a separate issue with my latex output (I never use it otherwise). I checked the source code too now, the parameter is only for latex output, it just does not mention it in the documentation itself. I've edited the question. Thank you

Comment: If you're not set on `kable`/`kableExtra`, you could use [`xtable`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html).

Comment: Yes, true. For my current case I don't need it, extra_css was enough. The next time I need to use more advanced formatting, I will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Lyngbakr pointed out in the comments, the function does not use the parameter hline_after in case the output is set to html. The parameter is only useful for latex output, it is just not mentioned explicitly in the documentation.

[source code](https://rdrr.io/cran/kableExtra/src/R/row_spec.R)

An alternative to using the hline_after parameter is using extra_css:

```
x <- knitr::kable(head(mtcars), "html")
kableExtra::row_spec(x, 2, extra_css = "border-bottom: 1px solid")
```

However, in more complicated tables this will mess with other row_spec and column_spec calls that you might be using.