# Table with package kableextra - how to add lines to the tables?

Tags: r, datatable, kableextra

has anyone an idea how to add a line  to this table created with the package kableextra?

Comment: `row_spec(c(2,4),hline_after=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks I just tried that but it doesnt work. could you post the whole code? that would be huge!

Comment: You could also try `kableExtra::row_spec(x, 2, extra_css = "border-bottom: 1px solid")` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53655983/row-spec-function-from-kableextra-does-not-create-a-horizontal-line-in-html-ou

Comment: Deleting sensitive information from the question is ok but you should atleast give some dummy data for the question so that it is useful for the future visitors.

Comment: Yes I am sorry for that. I will have to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the solution suggested by @TJ87 in the comments to create a horizontal line after every 2 rows.

```
library(kableExtra)

dt %>%
  kbl(caption = "Ü") %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = T, html_font = "Cambria") %>%
  row_spec(seq(2, nrow(dt), 2), extra_css = "border-bottom: 1px solid;")
```